# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function() - WP theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

We recently went through a website migration, PHP & WP upgrades. We are currently using a customized theme and keep getting the following error once we upgrade from PHP 5.6 to 7.0:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_resources() (...) /functions.php on line 220`

Already changed all `include` to `include_once`, but still getting the same error.

Anyone ever went through a similar issue?

Comment: In your IDE do a project search for `function get_resources` and see if it appears more than once.

Answer (score 3):

PHP introduced a function called `get_resources()` in PHP7:

> get_resources
>
> (PHP 7)
>
> get_resources — Returns active resources

Read full [manual entry here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-resources.php).

--

You'll have to upgrade your WordPress version to the latest out - the fix will be in there.

Comment: Thanks! We actually have all WP, themes & plugins upgraded up to the latest version, and tried deleting & reinstalling already... will have a look at the link now

Comment: @lauvdb hm, weird, I have my WordPress on 5.3 and all seems ok for me, if not, may have to download latest from the site directly and try that